# how can i make my submit button clickable once and still execute my php?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I have tried solving this but no matter what i try the button doesn't stay disabled for more than a second and won't execute my PHP script.

I have a restart button on my web page that when clicked sends an email to the admin to let them know a restart has been requested. I want this to be able to be clicked once then become greyed out to prevent multiple clicks. I want it to become active again after a certain amount of time

How can I get the Restart button to become clickable once (to rule out the possibility for too many script executions) and still execute the PHP script?

This is my code:

```
<form action=index.php method= "post">
<input type="submit" value="Request Restart" id="alertTimerButton" name="clickMe" onclick="countClicks();"/>

<?php
if (isset($_POST['clickMe']))
{
    exec("/anaconda3/bin/python /Users/shoot_station_5/Sites/simpleblogs/restartemail.py \"$input_val\""); 
} else{

}
```

I have tried adding various javascript such as:

```
function disable()
  $(document).ready(function(){
      $('.once-only').submit(function(){
      $(this).children('button').prop('disabled', true);
      alert("Thankyou a restart has been requested.");
  });
});
```

and

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var ClickCount = 0;
  function countClicks() {
    var clickLimit = 1; //Max number of clicks
    if(ClickCount>=clickLimit) {
      alert("a restart has already been requested");
      return false;
    }
    else
    {
      ClickCount++;
      alert("Thankyou a restart has been requested.");
      return true;
    }
  }
```

Comment: Use some javascript function to disable the button before submit the form.

Comment: I'd suggest using localstorage to store the date the button should be active again, otherwise the button will be enabled again if the page is refreshed.

Comment: Looks to me like you are submitting the page, and PHP is returning you to an identical page? That means a new JavaScript 'context' so need to do something a bit more sophisticated than just disabling the button. Do you want to re-enable after a set period of time, or on a specific event?

Comment: You can let php add an `$_SESSION["Clicked"] = "true"` when the button is clicked. Then you can add a class that disables the button, for example with  `<?php if(isset($_SESSION['Clicked']) && $_SESSION['Clicked'] == 'true') { echo "class = 'disabled'" } ?> `

Answer (score 2):

You have to change

```
onclick="countClicks();"
```

to

```
onclick="return countClicks();"
```

then your 2. solution does work.

Your 1. solution has multiple bugs. Don't wrap the code in a disable() function. And there is a # missing before 'button'.

I would do it like this:

```
onclick="disabled=true;"
```

That's enough.

Because you commented that you don't get your second solution running, here is the code:

```js
var ClickCount = 0;
function countClicks()
{
    var clickLimit = 1; //Max number of clicks
    if (ClickCount >= clickLimit)
    {
        alert("a restart has already been requested");
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        ClickCount++;
        alert("Thank you a restart has been requested.");
        return true;
    }
}
```

```html
<form action="#" method="post">
    <input type="button" value="Request Restart" id="alertTimerButton" name="clickMe" onclick="return countClicks();"/>
</form>
```

Comment: i have changed the countClicks(); to return countClicks(); but it still allows the second click

Comment: this works as intended on the button, and thank you for the code example. The only problem is that now the input type is button and it means it won't submit to the PHP so i cant get my script to run.

Comment: Try `onsubmit="return countClicks();"` attached to your `<form>` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Well the button is working as intended. Since you don't use ajax/xhr here you reload your page when the form is submitted. That's why the button is resetted. If you don't want to use ajax/xhr just save your "status" and maybe the time in a session variable and change the button property according to it. Your html/php would look like this

```
session_start();
if (isset($_POST['clickMe'])) {
    $_SESSION['restarted'] = time();
}
session_write_close();
$timeout = 300; // 5 min
$timer = time();
$disabled = false;
if (isset($_SESSION['restarted']) && ($timer - $_SESSION['restarted']) < $timeout) {
    $disabled = true;
}

.. (html stuff) ...
<form action=test.php method= "post">
    <input type="hidden" name="timer" value="<?php echo (isset($_SESSION['restarted']) ? $_SESSION['restarted'] : null)?>" />
    <input type="submit" <?php echo ($disabled ? 'disabled="true"' : null)?> value="Request Restart" id="alertTimerButton" name="clickMe"/>
</form>
```

And your js like this (if you use jquery)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('form').on('submit', function(e){
        alert("Thankyou a restart has been requested.");
        return true;
    });

    var restart_time = parseInt($('input[name="timer"]').val());
    var cur_time;
    setInterval(function(){ 
        cur_time = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000);
        if (cur_time - restart_time > 300000) {
            $('#alertTimerButton').prop('disabled', false);
        }
    }, 5000);
});
```

Edit: I fixed the code a bit and added a time check in javascript.